# Issue with NoSuchMethodException due to Java upgrade

Tags: java, java-8, runtime-error

In our application, we are making use of the `elementIsInEncryptionSpace` method from `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.XMLUtils` class, which was available in OpenJDK 1.8.0_292 in the **rt.jar** (runtime jar).

However, our server Java version got upgraded to OpenJDK 1.8.0_362, in this **rt.jar** this method is missing.

I'm also using `xmlsec.jar` in my application classpath which contains `XMLUtils.elementIsInEncryptionSpace` method, but as `rt.jar` already contains `XMLUtils.class` file without the method, my application still throws a `NoSuchMethodException`.

I found lots of links which suggested not to make any changes to rt.jar ever. Any suggestion to how I can resolve the issue. Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Find a different solution so that you don't need to use a class in a `com.sun` package. You are not supposed to use classes in `com.sun` and other packages that are not documented in the JDK API documentation; those classes are internal to the JDK and may change in any release, as you've experienced here.

Comment: `com.sun...` is how Sun implemented some libraries in the Java runtime. That's included in the oracle JDK. Now you use openjdk, which is not built by Oracle. That's why it's advised not to use vendor specific packages

Comment: Thanks @Jesper, I mentioned the third-party jar xmlsec.jar as it was having the method which was missing in the new version java rt.jar. The older version of java rt.jar was still having the method and its being used in the program very often so can anything be done so that I can use as a temp solution till I find a perm fix to the whole functionality flow.

Comment: Thanks @jhamon, would like to know your inputs as well for the above comments.

Comment: You need to look at your codebase to figure out how / where / why it is using that class.  Then you need to look for alternatives.  Your codebase shouldn't have been using it in the first place.  The `internal` in the package name is a big red flag.  It says **don't use this** ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for that method is very simple:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the element is in XML Encryption namespace and the local
 * name equals the supplied one.
 *
 * @param element
 * @param localName
 * @return true if the element is in XML Encryption namespace and the
   local name equals the supplied one
 */
public static boolean elementIsInEncryptionSpace(Element element, String localName) {
    if (element == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return EncryptionConstants.EncryptionSpecNS.equals(element.getNamespaceURI())
        && element.getLocalName().equals(localName);
}
```

... where

```
public static final String EncryptionSpecNS = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#";
```

You should be able to duplicate that functionality in your own codebase.

---

For the record, it is and always has been a bad idea to write your code to depend on internals of the JDK.  It is liable to break without any prior notice or even mention in release notes, etc ... as has happened here.

You think it is difficult now?  Just wait until you get to Java 17!

Comment: Hi @Stephen C, thanks for your inputs. I copied the required codes and few other which were from internal package, from the jar to into my application package and removed dependencies from the internal package so that future upgrades won't cause trouble.